# Why do Razor Pages projects still refer to/rely on MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm very confused about MVC and Razor Pages projects for ASP.NET Core 2.0.
In Visual Studio 2017 I do the following:

- New project
- Web ASP.NET Core Application (C#)
- Web Application (NOT Web Application MVC)

But when I open the .cs code of a page I see:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;  // <------- MVC?

namespace WebApplication2.Pages
{
    public class AboutModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "Your application description page.";
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it still refer to MVC if I selected a Razor Pages project?

My question rises from a deeper problem: I don't understand what documentation I have to follow! When I see a tutorial about razor or MVC I'm not sure if it applies to this type of project.

Comment: Because that’s where RazorPages seem to live. It doesn’t mean you’re using MVC.

Comment: @TylerH why did you go against the advice in the `model-view-controller` tag and use it anyway? The tag says "For Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, please use [asp.net-mvc] or [asp.net-core-mvc] tag instead." That tag was fine as it was.

Comment: @PeterB I did not 'go against the advice in the tag'. This question _isn't_ about ASP.NET _MVC_, it's about ASP.NET _Razor Pages_. I debated whether to use the ASP.NET Core MVC tag or just the generic MVC tag and opted for the latter since this is just about storing the Razor Pages functionality in an MVC name space, but if you disagree, we can use the ASP.NET Core MVC tag in general. It makes little difference as both are poor use cases of the tag here; the question would be equally useful with either tag _or_ with neither of them.

Comment: @PeterB As for "the tag was fine as it was" No, the tag used was [tag:asp.net-mvc]. The namespace OP is asking about and the technology used by OP is [tag:asp.net-core], so if any ASP.NET-related MVC tag were to be used, it should be [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]. So, the tag was decidedly _not_ fine as it was.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply because the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace is where the Microsoft team decided to put Razor. It doesn't mean that your project uses MVC, just that some classes it uses are located in a namespace that contains `MVC` in its name.

It is just a guess, but I believe it could simply be a historic thing. Razor used to really be just part of MVC, so it was under the MVC namespace but now that it doesn't need MVC to live they left it here for compatibility or consistency?

Comment: "*Razor used to really be just part of MVC, so it was under the MVC namespace but now that it doesn't need MVC*" It is there because it _does_ need the MVC Framework to work. You just don't have to use MVC-esque controllers and views to use Razor syntax now.